# Maximo - MxLoader Classification Upload with CLASSSTRUCTUREID

Tags: maximo

I'm able to upload classification to Maximo except `CLASSSTRUCTUREID` column, the process of MxLoader finish without any errors but the class structure field gets an Autokey value.

I tried to remove the Restricted option from the integration object structure (enforced to check Override) but on third row I got this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> Error 500: nested exception is: psdi.util.MXRequiredFieldException: BMXAA4195E - The Class Structure field requires a value."

The first two lines updated successfully on Maximo but, the other lines got the classification id in Classification Path and empty the parent classification (screenshot attached)

Any suggestion

Thanks

Maximo: 7.5.0.3
MxLoader: 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Maximo, after removing the restriction option from the integration object structure you must use option "Generate Schema/View XML" from action menu, for both Create and Update Operation.

it works with me after doing this.